# Partitioning a sequence into sets of unique pairs

Tags: python

I'm in need a of function which can split a sequence into pairs, and then combine them such that all elements in a combination is unique. I have tried a number of approaches using python's itertools, but have not found a solution.

To illustrate i would like a function which would take this sequence:
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

and split it into the following 3 combinations:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

it should also work for longer sequences, but does not have to handle sequences of odd length. eg.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

splits into the following 15 combinations:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 3], [2, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6]]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
[[1, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5]]
[[1, 5], [2, 3], [4, 6]]
[[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 6]]
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4]]
[[1, 6], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
[[1, 6], [2, 4], [3, 5]]
[[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
```

... and so on.

The CAS called Maple has this function implemented under the name [setpartition](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=combinat/setpartition).

Edit: fixed a critical late night typing error pointed out by wks, and clarified the outputs.

Comment: Yes, I must have been very tired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools`is indeed your friend:

```
from itertools import permutations

def group(iterable, n=2):
    return zip(*([iter(iterable)] * n))

for each in permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    print map(list, group(each))
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 5]]
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [6, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 2], [3, 6], [5, 4]]
[[1, 2], [4, 3], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
[[1, 2], [4, 5], [3, 6]]
...
```

**[EDIT]**
@FrederikNS: After you clarified your question [and found an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568081/partitioning-a-sequence-into-sets-of-unique-pairs/10570837#10570837), here is my solution:

```
from itertools import combinations

def setpartition(iterable, n=2):
    iterable = list(iterable)
    partitions = combinations(combinations(iterable, r=n), r=len(iterable) / n)
    for partition in partitions:
        seen = set()
        for group in partition:
            if seen.intersection(group):
                break
            seen.update(group)
        else:
            yield partition

for each in setpartition([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print each
print
for each in setpartition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    print each
```

Result:

```
((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 3), (2, 4))
((1, 4), (2, 3))

((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
((1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 6))
((1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 5))
((1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6))
((1, 3), (2, 5), (4, 6))
((1, 3), (2, 6), (4, 5))
((1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 6))
((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))
((1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5))
((1, 5), (2, 3), (4, 6))
((1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6))
((1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4))
((1, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5))
((1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5))
((1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4))
```

Comment: +1 this is great but i don't like the use of `each` as a name since it can be confused as a language construct from other languages.

Comment: This is cool, but unfortunately not what I was going for. I have clarified my question further.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it my self (pillmuncher's answer really gave me a nudge in the right direction, and the group function is entirely his):

```
def group(iterable, n=2):
    return zip(*([iter(iterable)] * n))

def set_partition(iterable, n=2):
    set_partitions = set()

    for permutation in itertools.permutations(iterable):
        grouped = group(list(permutation), n)
        sorted_group = tuple(sorted([tuple(sorted(partition)) for partition in grouped]))
        set_partitions.add(sorted_group)

    return set_partitions

partitions = set_partition([1,2,3,4], 2)
for part in partitions:
    print(part)
```

this prints :

```
((1, 4), (2, 3))
((1, 3), (2, 4))
((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def function(list):
    combinations = []
    for i in list:
        for i2 in list:
            if not [i2, i] in combinations:
                 combinations.append([i, i2])
    return combinations
```

This returns every possible combination.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That isn't what the question wanted - see the extra grouping in the example.  You've re-written itertools.combinations